# Import .mdf and .ldf Files into PostgreSQL (OS X El Capitan)

Tags: macos, postgresql, database-migration

Apologies if this has come up before - I have spend the entire day Googling this and have gotten no closer to working out what to do.

We have a database that we purchased from a 3rd party. This was first received years ago - long before I ever worked here. The person that previously set it up no longer works here so I can't ask them what they did and I can't find any documentation of the process that they used.

We have just received an update from the 3rd party however it wasn't really what I expected. I was lead to believe that it was going to be a bunch of csv files however it appears to be a database dump from a different system.

The received update contains a .mdf and a .ldf file as well as a couple of csv files. From what I can tell from online, .mdf and .ldf files are produced using SQL Server. I do not have any access to SQL Server and only use PostgreSQL.

I am just wondering if there is any way to import the .mdf and .ldf files into PostgreSQL? I am on OS X (El Capitan).

The only similar post I could find was:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17835/how-to-convert-sql-server-mdf-database-to-mac-os-postgresql-database-on-mac-os

However the suggested answers seemed to require using SQL Server - which I don't have any access to.

I also looked at:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL

However I'll be honest - I got pretty confused pretty quickly and a lot of them seemed to be Windows specific tools and I need Mac. (Or they are way too expensive!)

Has any one got any suggestions as I am completely stuck?

Comment: No, that's not possible. The mdf and ldf are binary files which are specific to SQL Server (and for which the format is not publicly available). You need to install SQL Server, import those files, then export the data as CSV and then import _that_ into Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Sorry - can't edit: @a_horse_with_no_name - Thanks for the quick response. That's disappointing - I was hoping that it would be possible without having to look at SQL Server (I only use PostGreSQL). From having a look around online I found this software called Navicat (which is available for Mac). The SQL Server edition (http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-sqlserver) seems like it might be a good shout for trying your suggestion - I can just use the free trial as this is a one off job I won't need to do again (hopefully!). Unless anyone has any better suggestions? (Easy = good!) Thanks

Comment: The SQL client I am using: http://sql-workbench.net can do that as well (export to CSV from SQL Server, import into Postgres) and is free. But you still need some SQL Server installation. SQL Server Express should be good enough if you stay below the 10GB limit. Btw: It's either PostgreSQL or Postgres. There is no capital G in the name.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So just to clarify - I'm going to need both a SQL Server installation and a separate client? Cool i'll look into that now. Unfortunately the .mdf file is 13gb so I'll have to find an alternative client. Many thanks for the help and sorry for the typo

Comment: The SQL client has nothing to do with the size of the .mdf file. SQL Server Express (which is free) does not support databases that are bigger than 10GB so I guess you are out of luck here (unless you want to *buy* a SQL Server license just to import that data). _If_ you have a running SQL Server with the mdf files, _any_ SQL client that can export CSV files will do. If you current SQL client can do that, use that.

Comment: Yeah I thought that was strange when you said that - just misread it sorry. Nah this is a one off (hopefully!) so can't stretch to a license and wouldn't want to commit to paying when I know nothing about which ones are decent. Just going to have to try a free trial and hopefully can get it done. Thanks

Comment: Navicat seems like a bust - I thought it was a full version on 14 day trial but the features I need are locked down. Has anyone got a software recommendation for an alternative? SQL Server Express looks perfect except for the 10gb limit. Thanks in advance